# pthread library manual and Is section 2 or section 7 of my Linux manual for POSIX API?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, network-programming, posix

1. My current Linux is Ubuntu 14, but I can't find the pthread manual on it.  I could find `pthread_create` on the man page (section 3), but not `pthread_cond_t` and `pthread_mutex_t`.  I assume pthread is part of POSIX, so shouldn't it be part of my Linux manual?  If not, how do I find it?
2. I am doing socket programming using POSIX.  However, both section 2 and section 7 of my man page has a `socket()` function. I can only find section 2 is for system calls, and section 7 is for "Miscellanea."  `inet_pton()` in section 3 of the man page.  My question: Where can I find the manual of POSIX manual? And if you could explain what sections of the man pages contain POSIX functions.

Comment: Make sure you are doing `man pthreads`. That is, with an "s" at the end.

Comment: `pthread_cond_t` and`pthread_mutex_t` are **types**, and the man pages generally cover interfaces (functions), not types. Try `man pthread_mutex_lock` or similar.

Comment: You won't find man page entries for types; only commands and functions.

Comment: Those are pthread opaque types. You can't do anything with them beyond passing them to pthread functions. Hence there is no need to document those apart from noting which functions return them and which functions take them as input - and that's provided in the pthread function man pages.

Comment: POSIX function calls will be in sections 2 and 3 mainly.  Some might be in special subsections (like 3S or 3C or more elaborate names).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Original answer

On my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (virtual machine), `man pthread_create` lists:

> ```
> PTHREAD_CREATE(3)          Linux Programmer's Manual         PTHREAD_CREATE(3)
> ```
>
> NAME
>
> ```
>   pthread_create - create a new thread
> ```
>
> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
>   #include <pthread.h>
>
>   int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
>                      void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
> ```
>
> Compile and link with -pthread.

It's listed in 'part 3' of the manual, rather than 'part 2'.

#### Revised answer

The question was updated to state that `pthread_create()` could be found.

In general, you won't find entries for types in the manual using `man pthread_mutex_t`, for example.  You might get information with `apropos pthread_mutex_t` instead (but it didn't help me).

The POSIX pthreads library functions will be documented in either section 2 or section 3 of the manual.  There may not be a special 'pthreads' section of the manual, though `man pthreads` shows me an extensive entry in section 7.

> Where can I find the manual of POSIX manual?

There isn't a separate POSIX section to the manual.  Many of the man pages cover POSIX functionality.  Some cover only POSIX functionality; many also cover GNU extensions to the POSIX functionality.

Any of sections 2, 3, 7 can contain information about POSIX functions.  Section 1 will contain some information about POSIX commands (and a lot of information about non-POSIX commands). Section 4 is about devices; section 5 is about file formats; section 6 contains information about games — these are generally not defined by POSIX.  Section 8 tends to be for system administration commands; they are not defined by POSIX either.

Comment: is the POSIX socket() function call in section 2 or section 7 of man page?  Thanks.

Comment: The `socket()` function is in section 2; section 7 is a more general discourse on the socket API as a whole, rather like `pthread_create` the function is documented specifically in section 3 but pthreads in general are discussed in section 7.

Answer (score 1):

Under Debian and derivatives, the POSIX man pages are contained in the `manpages-posix-dev` package, and once installed the `1posix` section will contain the command man pages and `3posix` will contain the API call man pages. The man pages for the POSIX headers should be in the `0posix` section, but this section is not made available.

Under Red Hat and derivatives, the POSIX man pages are in the `man-pages` package and are accessible via sections `0p`, `1p`, and `3p`.